# How do i validate or restrict enum type to accept only specific values

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In spring boot & hibernate, i'm making an API to change order status of a product, in orderStatus class i have two enum type fields, fromStatus and toStatus

My orderStatus class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class OrderStatus {

@Id
private Long orderProductId;

@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private Status fromStatus;

@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
private Status toStatus;
```

enum:

```
public enum Status{
ORDER_PLACED, CANCELLED, ORDER_CONFIRMED, ORDER_REJECTED, REFUND_INITIATED, ORDER_SHIPPED, DELIVERED, CLOSED,
RETURN_REQUESTED, RETURN_REJECTED, RETURN_APPROVED, PICK_UP_INITIATED, PICK_UP_COMPLETED, REFUND_COMPLETED
```

}

What i want to restrict is that when fromStatus is in ORDER_PLACED status, toStatus can only be
ORDER_CONFIRMED, ORDER_REJECTED or CANCELLED.

[Mapping chart for possible values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPDRm.png)

Currently i don't have any validations so when someone uses changeOrderStatus API they can change both fields to anything they want,

for eg: from_status: ORDER_PLACED and to_status: REFUND_INITIATED and i don't want that to happen.

Allowed toStatus values should depend on values in fromStatus

I could make a method to do so where i check each possible value with if conditions, i want to know if there's any smarter approach to this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to include a `validate(Status status)` in your Enum

like:

```java
enum Status {
    ORDER_PLACED {
        @Override
        public boolean validate(Status status) {
            return status== CANCELLED || status== ORDER_CONFIRMED || status== ORDER_REJECTED;
        }
    },
    CANCELLED{
        @Override
        public boolean validate(Status status) {
            return ...;
        }
    },
    ORDER_CONFIRMED {
        ...
    }, ...

    public abstract boolean validate(Status status)
}
```

A better way (but more complex) is to use a `StateMachine` like [Spring Statemachine](https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be sure that no one can save the `OrderStatus` with the wrong enum values, you have to build some business logic upon that.

I would suggest to move `fromStatus` and `toStatus` to the embedded object and implement the validation in this class.

```java
@Entity
public class OrderStatus {
  @Id
  private Long orderProductId;

  @Embedded
  private ComplexStatus status;
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
class ComplexStatus {
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private Status fromStatus;

  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private Status toStatus;

  // getters, setters, constructors
}
```